# SQL function to copy a custom field to the post_content en mass in for wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields, sqlbulkcopy

I need to copy the contents of key value for the key post_content to another table called wp_posts into the key values for post_content.

Is there anyway to do this in bulk, like all posts in the database?  This would help me greatly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first post_content is in wp_postmeta (a custom field). Then you would copy from the wp_postmeta to the wp_posts;

```
UPDATE wp_posts,wp_postmeta 
SET wp_posts.post_content = wp_postmeta.meta_value 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='abstract'
```